# Invoke not working Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, invoke

Can you tell me what's wrong in this piece of code? It does not call the Invoke function

```cs
    public class ReazioneBonus : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider){

        string nomeBonus;

        if(collider.gameObject.name.Contains("Pallina")){
            nomeBonus = gameObject.name;
            Debug.Log("bonus colpito");
            Debug.Log("il nome del bonus è " + nomeBonus);

            if(nomeBonus == "PaddleLungo(Clone)"){ //Allunga il paddle per 5 secondi
                Debug.Log("attivazione Paddle Lungo");
                Destroy(gameObject);
                Debug.Log("bonus colpito da " + Pallina.ultimoGiocatoreToccato);
                if(Pallina.ultimoGiocatoreToccato.name == "AvversarioRosso" || Pallina.ultimoGiocatoreToccato.name == "AvversarioVerde"){
                    Debug.Log("giocatore riconosciuto");
                    AllungaPaddleVerticale();
                    Invoke ("RipristinaPadVerticale", 5f); //non chiama la funzione
                }else if(Pallina.ultimoGiocatoreToccato.name == "AvversarioBlu" || Pallina.ultimoGiocatoreToccato.name == "AvversarioGiallo"){
                    Debug.Log("giocatore riconosciuto");
                    AllungaPaddleOrizzontale();
                    Invoke ("RipristinaPadOrizzontale", 5f); //non chiama la funzione
                }
            }
        }
    }


    void AllungaPaddleVerticale(){
        Pallina.ultimoGiocatoreToccato.transform.localScale += new Vector3(3F, 0, 0);
    }

    void AllungaPaddleOrizzontale(){
        Pallina.ultimoGiocatoreToccato.transform.localScale += new Vector3(0, 0, 3F);
    }

    void RipristinaPadVerticale(){
        Debug.Log("ripristino il paddle");
        Pallina.ultimoGiocatoreToccato.transform.localScale += new Vector3(-3F, 0, 0);
    }

    void RipristinaPadOrizzontale(){
        Debug.Log("ripristino il paddle");
        Pallina.ultimoGiocatoreToccato.transform.localScale += new Vector3(0, 0, -3F);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You destroy the gameObject of that monobehavior:

```
Destroy(gameObject);
```

How would these methods be invoked if the monobehavior itself is already destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

When you destroy a GameObject all attached MonoBehaviours' active invokes are cancelled. This to prevent bad references.

Simply destroy the GameObject after your invokes are complete:

```
public class ReazioneBonus : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider){

        string nomeBonus;

        if(collider.gameObject.name.Contains("Pallina")){
            nomeBonus = gameObject.name;
            Debug.Log("bonus colpito");
            Debug.Log("il nome del bonus è " + nomeBonus);

            if(nomeBonus == "PaddleLungo(Clone)"){ //Allunga il paddle per 5 secondi
                Debug.Log("attivazione Paddle Lungo");
                Debug.Log("bonus colpito da " + Pallina.ultimoGiocatoreToccato);
                if(Pallina.ultimoGiocatoreToccato.name == "AvversarioRosso" || Pallina.ultimoGiocatoreToccato.name == "AvversarioVerde"){
                    Debug.Log("giocatore riconosciuto");
                    AllungaPaddleVerticale();
                    Invoke ("RipristinaPadVerticale", 5f); //non chiama la funzione
                }else if(Pallina.ultimoGiocatoreToccato.name == "AvversarioBlu" || Pallina.ultimoGiocatoreToccato.name == "AvversarioGiallo"){
                    Debug.Log("giocatore riconosciuto");
                    AllungaPaddleOrizzontale();
                    Invoke ("RipristinaPadOrizzontale", 5f); //non chiama la funzione
                }
            }
        }
    }


    void AllungaPaddleVerticale(){
        Pallina.ultimoGiocatoreToccato.transform.localScale += new Vector3(3F, 0, 0);
    }

    void AllungaPaddleOrizzontale(){
        Pallina.ultimoGiocatoreToccato.transform.localScale += new Vector3(0, 0, 3F);
    }

    void RipristinaPadVerticale(){
        Debug.Log("ripristino il paddle");
        Pallina.ultimoGiocatoreToccato.transform.localScale += new Vector3(-3F, 0, 0);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    void RipristinaPadOrizzontale(){
        Debug.Log("ripristino il paddle");
        Pallina.ultimoGiocatoreToccato.transform.localScale += new Vector3(0, 0, -3F);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

}
```